# how to get the iOS build from Cordova VS2015

Tags: ios, cordova

Having some issued trying to get the xcode project for my hybrid app built on Tools for Apache Cordova. Getting the android build was quite simple all I had to do was set the build target to 'device' and it worked fine. Now I am seeing some issues with the iOS. I do not see 'device' in the target list, and the only item I can really do is the Ripple. How can I get the build for my project for iOS?

I did read some things and from what I read everyone was mentioning that we need to remote build it to a Mac? I have a Mac, but I would very much like it if I can just get the proper build without doing the remote build thing. Is this possible?

2 questions:

1) How can I get the build fro my project for iOS?
follow up question 2) Do I NEED to remote build for that? Or is there another way?

**EDIT**
I do have a Mac, but it's at my office. I was hoping to just get the build so I have it ready to put on my Mac when I get it.

Comment: You can use Phonegap Build. To build IOS app manually then you need a Mac. Please check document in cordova site: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide

Comment: Hmm.. just a little confused on your wording. You say I can use phonegap build? what's the difference between that a manual iOS app?

Comment: Phonegap Build is a tool to build Phonegap app in all platform. You only need upload source (a zip file 'www' ) and it will build your app automatically. In other case, if you want to build you app for each platform then you can buid manual. See: https://build.phonegap.com/

Comment: Right, but I used Cordova (from my research they are two separate things and I've also read you use one or the other). You're saying I use PhoneGap as well?

Comment: It depend on what kind of your app and many things. If you focus in hybrid app then Cordova (Phonegap) is best solutions: HTML5 + JS for all platform. If your app need best performance (game, others.. app) then you should focus in native app (IOS: Object C, Swift; Android: Java; WindowPhone: C#;..)

Comment: I already used Cordova though. I'm just trying to get the iOS build of it. I already have the android one.